# usage of "no matter...or"

Tags: idioms

Can I use "no matter...or" in the following way? Also can anyone help me verify
the whole sentence?

> When I first joined the lab,  Haijing provided a lot of help for me no matter in study or in life.

Comment: Note that *no matter* means *it doesn't matter / it's irrelevant*, and is used to emphasise that whatever comes *after* it doesn't affect the validity of whatever you said *before* it - normally in contexts where there's a possibility your audience might have thought otherwise unless you explicitly make that point. So as @jwpat7 says, this sentence is *not* a valid way of using it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The phrase “no matter” is not correctly used in your example sentence.  One can add the word *whether* and correctly say “no matter whether in study or in life”.   However, that is somewhat clumsy, and phrasings like  “whether in study or in life”, “both in study and in life”, and “in study and in life” are to be preferred.  For example,

> When I first joined the lab, Haijing provided much help for me both in study and in life.

Comment: That would be an excellent answer on writersSE. On ELU, the question relates to whether or not *or* is appropriate against *no matter ...*, and not a better alternative to *no matter*. Editing, proofreading and rephrasing are off-topic on ELU.

Comment: @Kris, what's writersSE? Can you give me a link?

Comment: @FihopZz http://writers.stackexchange.com